# control alt no funciona en PyCharm

Tags: python, python-2.7, twitter-api, twitter

Estoy haciendo un bot para twitter con Python y me he descargado el IDE de PyCharm.

Para algunas líneas necesito escribir el @ pero cuando pulso ctrl alt @ no me funciona ¿Alguien sabría decirme por que es esto?

Comment: Hola, creo que necesitamos más información para contestarte. ¿Podrías explicar tu pregunta un poco más detalladamente? Gracias.

Comment: Prueba con AltGr, a ver que pasa.

Comment: después de la actualización de los últimos días me sucedió lo mismo, con la solución aportada por Vacendak pude resolverlo perfectamente. Muchísimas gracias Vacendak

Comment: De acuerdo, ya me funciona, muchas gracias.

Comment: tengo el mismo problema, como lo mencionó Vacendak y aparece en el foro de https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-88508?_ga=2.22726008.23096158.1565206475-1912701841.1565206475
funciona bien para windows... pero alguien conoce la solución trabajando en el sistema de iOS de MAC???... muchas gracias.... Simón.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acabo de encontrar la solución en los foros de Jetbrains: Adding "actionSystem.force.alt.gr=true" to the bottom of the ...\bin\idea.properties file "solved" the issue for me.

Lo acabo de hacer y funciona perfectamente, y por lo que pone la gente es un BUG de Pycharm 2019.1 , y pasa en todos los idiomas.
Por si sirve de ayuda he editado el archivo `\bin\idea.properties` con Notepad++ para asegurarme de que no se producían cambios indeseados al guardar.
Obviamente el comando hay que añadirlo sin las comillas:
`actionSystem.force.alt.gr=true`

Espero que sirva de ayuda, porque este problema lo va a tener todo el mundo que use esta versión hasta que Jetbrains arregle el BUG.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que Eneko se ha confundido al hacer la pregunta: Lo que no funciona en Pycharm es la tecla `AltGr`, con lo que es imposible escribir los caracteres `[]{}\|@#`.
A mí me pasa lo mismo y sólo es dentro de Pycharm, como podéis comprobar ya que aquí no he tenido ningún problema para escribirlas.
No creo que se pueda explicar el problema más detalladamente. He buscado por todas partes y en los menús de configuración de Pycharm, pero no encuentro la solución. Ni en la ayuda de Jetbrains, ni en Stackoverflow en inglés. Por cierto la codificación está en UTF-8, por si alguien piensa que es eso. De hecho los acentos y caracteres españoles si que funcionan. Lo único que no funciona es la tecla `AltGr`